# Cannot access su in fedora 17

Tags: su, fedora-17

I am using Fedora 17.
by mistaken, I have given full permission as root, for all the files in

> /usr/bin

My command was

> chmod 777 *

and also I gave full permission for a file(I can't remember the name of the file) in /proc.
my command was

> chmod 777 [filename]

Now when I enter the su command and enter the password it says

> su: incorrect password

can someone help me to fix this.

Comment: 777 is for full read, write or execution permission. Try logging in as single user mode and reset password.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change root's password:

1. Boot from a LiveCD.
2. Open a root shell.
3. Mount your system partition: (replace `/dev/sda1` with your partition)

   ```
   mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   ```
4. Chroot into your installed system:

   ```
   chroot /mnt
   ```
5. Change root's password:

   ```
   passwd root
   ```